# 301 redirect for url containing underscores

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to

redirect /directsystems/education/index/name/system_one

TO

`http://www.mysite.com/directsystems/education/index/name/system-one`

Can you please show me the 301 redirect rule for htaccess? As i want to redirect undescores with hypens

Answer (score 1):

To replace all underscores `_` with hyphen `-` in URI, use following rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^\_]+)_([^\_]+)(_.*)$ /$1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\_]+)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

This redirects a URL of:

`http://localhost/directsystems/education/index/my_name/system_one`

to

`http://localhost//directsystems/education/index/my-name/system-one`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ $1-$2
```